# What does the EC Private key version field mean?

Tags: ecc, pkcs1, pkcs8

I have read the question [Converting ECC Private key to PKCS#1 format](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84327/converting-ecc-private-key-to-pkcs1-format). And I understood that the value of the version field of the traditional EC private key is `01`.

We can use the command `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt` to convert the traditional key to unencrypted) PKCS#8 format. Once the key is converted the version field of the converted key is `00`.

What is the meaning of these version field? If I see a version field value as `01`, Does that confirm the key is not in PKCS#8 format?

Comment: public static PrivateKey generatePrivate(String privateKeyPEM){
        java.util.Base64.Decoder decoder = java.util.Base64.getDecoder();
        byte [] decodedBytes = decoder.decode(privKeyPEM);
        KeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decodedBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC","BC");
        return kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
}

Answer (score 1):

You might be misinterpreting the message you link to.

The private key is represented as a structure that comes from SEC and includes a "version field" which always has value "1".

When the private key is encoded in PKCS#8, then the previous structure is "wrapped": PKCS#8 includes some identifier of the used algorithm ("this is an EC key") and an OCTET STRING that contains *the whole of* the private key structure as specified above, including the version field with the value "1".

The PKCS#8 wrapper *also* has a "version" field, normally with value "0". So, in PKCS#8, you get both.

When there is a "version" field, this is a mechanism to potentially support other layouts -- when such things are defined. Right now, no other layout is defined, so all you can do with another value is to make the object undecodable by some software.

Comment: I am using Bouncycastle to generatePrivate, which throws InvalidKeySpecException if I pass the private key (with version 1), once the key is PKCS#8 wrapped (version 0) then Bouncycasle is able to generate the private key. Some where in the code Bouncycastle checks for version to be 0 for the PrivateKeyInfo. How should I interpret this?

Comment: The problem is not one of version. The problem is that BouncyCastle expects the private key as a PKCS#8 object. If what you provide is not a proper PKCS#8 object, then you get an exception.

Comment: Understood. So is there a way that I can confirm that the private key stored in PEM is a proper PKCS#8 formatted key. Can I use openssl asn1parse -i -in mykep.pem and look into the version, if the version is not '0' does that confirm it is not a proper PKCS#8 formatted private key. During experiments I have observed that the version of the proper PKCS#8 wrapped private key always shown version 0. Is there a way to confirm this?

Comment: Use: `openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -in mykep.pem`   This will try to read the file as a PKCS#8 file. If it works, then it is a PKCS#8 file.