# Why PEM encodings of EC public and private keys use different headers?

Tags: openssl, ecc, pem

Manual page for OpenSSL `ec` command states:

```
   The PEM private key format uses the header and footer lines:

    -----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
    -----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----

   The PEM public key format uses the header and footer lines:

    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

1. What standard does this base upon (if any)?
2. Why 'EC' is indicated in the private key header/footer, but not in the public? I assume that this is a piece of "meta-information" describing the content, so why is it missing from the public part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For RSA, the RSAPublicKey structure is defined in PKCS#1 standard and SubjectPublicKeyInfo defined for X509 simply uses definitions from PKCS#1. So there are two forms for RSA public keys which PEM format distinguishes :

- one with 'RSA' - RSAPublicKey
- one without 'RSA' - SubjectPublicKeyInfo wrapping RSAPublicKey

EC is defined in RFC5915 and does not provide the ECPublicKey structure instead referring to SubjectPublicKeyInfo from X509 as a vehicle for public key sharing. Therefore 'BEGIN EC PUBLIC KEY' would simply be equivalent to 'BEGIN PUBLIC KEY' which uses SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure.

In short : this discrepancy is due to historical reasons and the order in which things were invented and standardized.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question, this is based on the RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5915 (section 4)

The missing algorithm name has to do with the encoding format used while encoding i.e. pkcs#1 vs pkcs#8. The first one doesn't contain the algorithmIdentifier and hence the algo name(EC, RSA etc.) is included in the label. However, pkcs#8 encapsulates the algorithm identifier and hence it's omitted from the label.

for example, pkcs#8 format for private key is this:

```
PrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
   version                   Version,
   privateKeyAlgorithm       PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier,
   privateKey                PrivateKey,
   attributes           [0]  IMPLICIT Attributes OPTIONAL }

Version ::= INTEGER

PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier ::= AlgorithmIdentifier

PrivateKey ::= OCTET STRING

Attributes ::= SET OF Attribute
```

To clarify, there is nothing preventing one to represent the public key in pkcs#1 format and thus creating a header of the type: -----BEGIN EC PUBLIC KEY-----. So it seems that the particular encoding produced is according to the default encoding set for the tool(I am not sure of this though). Nevertheless, any decent tool/library should be able to gracefully handle either format, even when different formats are used for the public and private keys of the same key-pair.

Comment: And the other "BEGIN PUBLIC KEY"?

Comment: updated my answer. However, exactly why openssl behaves this particular way, I do not know.

Comment: But the public key is not written in PKCS#8. `openssl asn1dump` shows a very simple structure, containing just two "OBJECT"s and one "BIT STRING". It is something else.

Comment: (starting answering own question) https://security.stackexchange.com/a/84331/50647 tells about SEC-1 specification, which suggests ASN.1 encoding for EC keys (both private and public). It looks like OpenSSL follows this recommendation and then adds (not really specified anywhere?) PEM headers.

Comment: PKCS1 is the algorithm-specific form for RSA only not EC. The EC privatekey syntax was defined by SECG SEC1, as stated in rfc5915; the EC publickey syntax was defined by X9.62 and adopted with some restrictions by PKIX (rfc3279 and rfc5480) and SEC1. And PKCS8 is the generic format only for privatekey; for publickey it is X.509 and mostly the PKIX profile thereof.